# Regular expression to capture optional named group

Tags: c#, regex, regex-group

I'm trying to write a regular expression for parsing address.

My address strings have next format: `AddressLine (City) SomeFixedText`

The only problem that `(City)` part is optional. For example:

```
Abingdon Road (Oxford) Water Network Pumping
Adderbury Water Network Pumping
```

Without capturing optional group I've come up with following expression:

```
(?<Line>.*) \((?<City>.*)\) Water Network Pumping
```

But of course it doesn't not handle the second case. I tried to use an optional group:

```
(?<Line>.*)( \((?<City>.*)\))? Water Network Pumping
```

But in this case Line and City are captured incorrectly for the first case.

Here is the fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/crHlta

How can I handle this situation?

Comment: Use `(?<Line>.*?)(?:\s+\((?<City>.*?)\))? Water Network Pumping`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I disagree with the decision to close this question on the grounds that a bit of targeted advice for the OP would better help him learn what went wrong

Comment: @RomanKolida in essence the problem (and the tiny change of `.*` -> `.*?`) is that .* matches all of the input including the city name in brackets. THen your optional clause says "is there a city left in the data, in brackets?" - even when there is it will decide there isn't because the greedy consumption by `.*` has consumed the city too. Because city is allowed to be absent, the match succeed, even though the city was captured into the wrong thing. By making the matching creep forwards (pessimistic) rather than greedy (consume all and work backwords), `.*` matches upto the first bracket

Comment: You could also manage it by making the first quantifier "match everything that is not a bracket" like `(?<Line>[()]*)(?:\s+\((?<City>.*?)\))? Water Network Pumping` - ultimately if you're going to have "optional things that follow mandatory things" you have to make sure that the "mandatory thing" doesn't match too much and eat up all your optional things

Comment: You could use this: ((?<Line>.*?)\((?<City>.*?)\)\sWater Network Pumping|(?<Line>.*?)\sWater Network Pumping)

Comment: The only problem here is that `.*` was used instead of `.*?`. Hence, the duplicates are appropriate.